# Iterate for sibling elements and filter out specific elements at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have the following html which I can't modify because its being dynamically generated by a third party company I'm working with...

```html
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><font>data A</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><font>data B - Title</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><font>data B - Content</font></td>
</tr>
<!--THERE'S LIKE 65 OF THESE HIDDEN INPUT FIELDS GENERATED ON PAGE...-->
<input type="hidden" name="inpA" value>
<input type="hidden" name="inpB" value>
<input type="hidden" name="inpC" value>
<input type="hidden" name="inpD" value>
<input type="hidden" name="inpE" value>
<input type="hidden" name="inpF" value>
<!--....-->
<tr>
  <td><font>data C - Title</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><font>data C - Content</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><font>data D - Title</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><font>data D - Content</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using a do while loop to iterate through a table for sibling elements.  **But I want my do while loop to exclude the `input` sibling elements**.  How can I "skip" over them?

```js
//my specific areas to target in my table.  I will add more selectors to this eventually...
let mTitles = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-child(1) font');
for (let i = 0, len = mTitles.length; i < len; i++) {
  
  //get the closest parent target element to help track other sibling elements
  let mParent = mTitles[i].closest('tr');
  
  //Focusing on the first selector...
  if (i == 0) {
    //lets test our first selector data
    console.log(`our parent element: ${mParent.nodeName}`);
    console.log(`whats inside our parent elment: ${mParent.innerHTML}`);
    
    //if the next sibling element is not null...
    if (mParent.nextElementSibling != null) {
        //loop through the rest of the sibling elements and capture them
      let nextSibling = mParent;
      let n = 0;
      do {
        n = n + 1;
        console.log(nextSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
        nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
      } while(n < 11); //set the range of sibling elements to consider in our loop   
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see when you run this in code pen, the gap between data B and data C....

[image]

I just want to remove that gap (i.e. exclude the input elements). How can I improve my logic to get to my goal?

You can see it action here - https://codepen.io/kensleylewis/pen/bGodoQW

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it correct that you do not want to consider `mParent` itself, but only its siblings? Also, is it correct that you do not check whether `nextElement.nextElementSibling` exists before using it? That may result in a runtime error.

Comment: Thanks Oskar, I have already updated on logic to check against that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the content of `innerHTML` and do a `console.log` only if the string `length > 0` or if the string is `!== ""`.

```js
if (nextSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML !== "") {
  console.log(nextSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
}
```

```js
//my specific areas to target in my table.  I will add more selectors to this eventually...
const mTitles = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-child(1) font');
for (let i = 0, len = mTitles.length; i < len; i++) {
  //get the closest parent target element to help track other sibling elements
  const mParent = mTitles[i].closest('tr');

  //Focusing on the first selector...
  if (i === 0) {
    //lets test our first selector data
    console.log(`our parent element: ${mParent.nodeName}`);
    console.log(`whats inside our parent element: ${mParent.innerHTML}`);

    //if the next sibling element is not null...
    if (mParent.nextElementSibling !== null) {
      //loop through the rest of the sibling elements and capture them
      let nextSibling = mParent;
      let n = 0;
      do {
        n++;
        const nextInnerHTML = nextSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
        if (nextInnerHTML !== '') {
          console.log(nextSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
        }
        nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
      } while (n < 11);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font>data A</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font>data B - Title</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font>data B - Content</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--THERE'S LIKE 65 OF THESE HIDDEN INPUT FIELDS GENERATED ON PAGE...-->
    <input type="hidden" name="inpA" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpB" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpC" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpD" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpE" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpF" value>
    <!--....-->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font>data C - Title</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font>data C - Content</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font>data D - Title</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font>data D - Content</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Check for input elements

We can check whether `<tr>` only contains `<input>` children:

```js
const shouldSkip = Array.from(tr.children).every(child => child.nodeName === "INPUT");
```

Otherwise, we know that the `<input>`s are *not* placed in `<tr>`s, which the browser fixes to have every `<input>` in their own `<tr>`. Thus we can check whether a `<tr>` has only one element, and if that element is an `<input>`:

```js
const shouldSkip = tr.children.length === 1 && tr.children[0].nodeName === "INPUT"`;
```

This way, we don't create a new array for each `<tr>`, and only do two comparisons instead of one for *each* child of `<tr>`, which is potentially more complex. For that reason, **this way is what I recommend**.

## Check for text content

As previously mentioned, every misplaced `<input>`s will be inserted into their own `<tr>`. And since `<input>`s of type "hidden" don't produce any text content, we can check whether the `<tr>` has any text content at all:

```js
const shouldSkip = tr.textContent.length === 0;
```

## Solution example

As any of the previous solutions should do, I chose one to showcase. Again, this is the approach I suggest for the reasons stated earlier:

```js
const mTitles = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-child(1) font');

/* Personally, a regular for-loop let's me think
 * that the iterator-variable (i) will be of interest,
 * though here we are only interested in the elements
 * of the iterable. Hence I suggest using a foreach-loop.
 */
for (const mTitle of mTitles) {
  const mParent = mTitle.closest('tr');

  console.log(`our parent element: ${mParent.nodeName}`);
  console.log(`whats inside our parent elment: ${mParent.innerHTML}`);

  let nextSibling = mParent;
  let n = 0;
  while (n < 11 && nextSibling) {
    const containsOnlyInputs = nextSibling.children.length === 1
      && nextSibling.children[0].nodeName === "INPUT";
    if (!containsOnlyInputs) {
      console.log(nextSibling.innerHTML);
      ++n;
    }

    nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><font>data A</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font>data B - Title</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font>data B - Content</font></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpA" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpB" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpC" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpD" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpE" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="inpF" value>
    <!-- ... -->
    <tr>
      <td><font>data C - Title</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font>data C - Content</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font>data D - Title</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font>data D - Content</font></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## End note

I recommend:

- to use `const` instead of `let` if you *know* you won't reassign the variable.
- to use a *for...of*-loop instead of a *for*-loop, if applicable. A *for*-loop (to me) suggests that the iterator-variable (usually `i`) will of interest, though here we are only interested in the individual elements of the array.
- to check whether `nextElement.nextElementSibling` is non-nullish before using it. Obviously this is redundant if you check it by other means, for example by setting the *while*-loop's limit (see `n < 11`) to the amount of following siblings.

As your code is currently, effectively only consider the following siblings of `mParent`. With this (and also tying into my last recommendation) I would suggest a loop of this form:

```js
let n = 0;
let sibling = mParent; // Assign previous node of the node to start with

// Assign the next sibling, and
// check whether it is not "falsy" (i.e. not equal to null or undefined)
while (n < 11 && (sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling)) {
  const shouldSkip = sibling.children.length === 1
    && sibling.children[0].nodeName === "INPUT";
  if (shouldSkip) continue; // Now we can use `continue`!

  console.log(sibling.innerHTML);
  ++n;
}
```

Even though this is a one-liner I would still recommend it for the following reasons:

- I see this pattern being used quite frequently, which disambiguates it for most.
- Now we can use `continue` to skip an iteration, ridding us of the if-statement I used before, which makes the program flow easier to understand.
- If unknown to one, it *still* is not too hard to understand really, is it?